# How do I get argument values inferred from usage?

Tags: c#

So I'm following through some code snippets for AutoInjector and Automapper online, and noticed something that I don't really understand.

In the code, AutoInjector is Registering Automapper for use in this line.

`container.Register(() => config.CreateMapper(container.GetInstance));`

I noticed that `container.GetInstance` isn't having anything passed into it.

After some tinkering, I tried to do `var instance = container.GetInstance();` in a console app, but it gives the error `The type arguments for method 'Container.GetInstance<TService>() cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Obviously, the arguments being passed are inferred from the outer method `config.CreateMapper()`

I was wondering if there was a way to step through the code so I can see what is being passed into `container.GetInstance()`. When I step through the code, it just steps over the line and doesn't show me what's being passed into the method.

Comment: What is the argument type of `CreateMapper`?

Comment: I know what a method group is. My question has nothing to do with method groups. I want to know what argument is being implicitly passed into the method.

Comment: `CreateMapper(Func<Type, object> serviceCtor);`

Comment: Read the 2nd answer in the linked question regarding the Linq usage.

Comment: *“Obviously, the arguments being passed are inferred from the outer method `config.CreateMapper()`”* – Why exactly is that so obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that `container.GetInstance` isn't having anything passed into it.

Because nothing is. The argument of `CreateMapper` is a *delegate*, more specifically a `Func<Type, object>`; So `config.CreateMapper(container.GetInstance)`  is exactly the same as if you'd written:

```
config.CreateMapper(type => GetInstance(type));
```

You are not passing in any concrete arguments at that point in time, you are simply "informing" `container` how to create a mapper for any given `type`,

Its the same as the following LINQ usage in this trivial code snippet (hence the possible duplicate comment):

```
public static string ToString<T>(T arg) => arg.ToString();

var ints = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
var strs = ints.Select(ToString); //or ints.Select(i => ToString(i))
```

What arguments are passed into `ToString` in the `Select` call? Well, none, you are only informing `Select` how to map an `int` to a `string`, you are not processing any integers yet (you wouldn't be able to anyways, the enumeration is empty!). The arguments will be passed into the delegate (or not) when the enumeration *is enumerated*.

Your code is the same, an argument typed `Type` (if any) will be passed into `GetInstance` whenever a mapper needs to be created for any given type. The code you've posted is irrelevant as to *when* and for *what* specific `type` that happens, thats why while debugging you simply step over that line.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateMapper` expects as its argument a function which takes an input of `Type` and returns `object`.

```
Func<Type, object>
```

Looks like `container.GetInstance` is one such function.

---

Since you seem to be interested in the internals, here they are:

[MapperConfiguration.cs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/1aea7260e40d21471d70a9d0a7ab99b91feba024/src/AutoMapper/MapperConfiguration.cs)

```
public IMapper CreateMapper() => new Mapper(this);
```

[Mapper.cs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/8dd104aa7390c12c97c4195cce6f6ff66de24f51/src/AutoMapper/Mapper.cs)

```
public Mapper(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
    : this(configurationProvider, configurationProvider.ServiceCtor)
{
}

public Mapper(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, Func<Type, object> serviceCtor)
{
    _configurationProvider = configurationProvider;
    _serviceCtor = serviceCtor;
    DefaultContext = new ResolutionContext(new ObjectMappingOperationOptions(serviceCtor), this);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is, and I understand that much. But is there a way to step through the a specific usage of the code, and see what is being passed as the argument?

Comment: You can look through the source code for Automapper. This is an external library and the only way to look at what's going inside is through a disassembler or the source code itself.

Comment: *“My guess is that Type is likely a generic”* – Given that you’ve now made the effort to look at the source code, you can remove that guess. There is nothing generic about the method.